# Environment error while installing django-cms on Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pip, django-cms

I get the following error after passing the configuration of Django-cms. A couple of non-python packages seem to be missing.

```
EnvironmentError: Pillow is not compiled with PNG support, see 'Libraries installation issues' documentation section: http://djangocms-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/libraries.html.
Pillow is not compiled with JPEG support, see 'Libraries installation issues' documentation section: http://djangocms-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/libraries.html
```

From where and how do I install these packages? And in which directory do I install them? The Python root directory or the django-cms virtualenv lib?

Comment: What operating system (and version thereof) are you using? The error is because you're missing some (non-Python) libraries on your system. How to install them varies widely between operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on Ubuntu 14.04 or later, run `sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk`, then re-install `Pillow` in your virtualenv (or re-create the virtualenv).

Comment: The libraries have to be installed into the Python root folder or the virtualenv?

Comment: These libraries are C libraries and should be installed system wide. That's why you should use "sudo apt-get" (Ubuntus package manager).

Comment: So I first install these libraries, then I create a virtualenv, install pillow and django-cms using pip. Is that right? Sorry, I am new at this!

Comment: That is correct. In general you have to install C dependencies first using apt-get before installing Python packages depending on them, though sometimes it's hard to know exactly what libraries are needed. In those cases googeling the error often helps (that's what I do). And no problem at all, we all have to start somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That resolved all errors. The django-cms package is up and running. You deserve a standing ovation!